Why my state is not updating even if everything is okay?
Why my state is not updating even if everything is okay?


class TodoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        body: BlocBuilder<TodoBloc, TodoState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            final bloc = context.read<TodoBloc>();

            if (state is InitTodoState) {
              if (state.todoList == null) return Offstage();

              if (state.todoList!.isEmpty) {
                return Center(child: Text('No todos available'));
              }

              return ListWidget();
            } else {
              return Loading(); // Show loading indicator
            }
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            await init(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> init(BuildContext context) async {
    final getTodoListUseCase = GetTodoListUseCase(
      firebaseTodo: TodoRepositoryImpl(FirebaseApiImpl()),
      serverTodo: TodoRepositoryImpl(LocalApiImpl(RestApiImpl())),
    );

    var params;
    final res = await getTodoListUseCase.call(params);

    res.fold((failure) {
      print("Failed to fetch todo list");
    }, (todoList) {
      print("Fetched todo list with ${todoList.length} items");
      context.read<TodoBloc>().add(InitEvent(todoList));
    });
  }
}

while updating the bloc even if iam passing a new state then also I am not updating state the bloc is correctly iinitialize and the data is also comming I am not undetstanding why becouse if I change the routing way s comming but its not way to correct code practice how to do it?

In which piece of code are you proving the TodoBloc? Is it on the app level?
